# Как в форме передавать ajax помимо всех полей еще и прикрепленный файл?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы форма передавала помимо значений всех полей формы, еще и прикрепленный файл?
Сейчас сделал так:

```
   $('#content').on('submit', '#add_event_form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
        var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
        var m_data=$(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: m_method,
            url: m_action,
            data: m_data,
                success: function(result){
                    $('.event_form_action').hide('slow');
                    $('.add_event_text').height(48);
                    $('#content .dashboard-list').html(result);
                    $("#add_event_form").trigger('reset');
                }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может проще использовать готовый плагин для работы с формами? Есть поддержка загрузки файлов, и не нужно запросы руками делать.

[jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать FormData

[Первая попавшаяся ссылка](http://true-coder.ru/php/ispolzovanie-obekta-formdata-dlya-zagruzki-fajlov.html)